# How would i update the useState value from a seperate file in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to access and update the state of an object from two seperate files, i can change it if i use a local useState for each files but that is not going to work,

I have tried many different solutions, using custom hooks and local state but none of them fix my problem, i have been stuck on this issue for ~5 hours and it is driving me crazy, any help would be appreciated.

I think the problem is that i am trying to call the hook from inside a return statement, but i cannot  think of any alternatives to doing this as that is where it is being rendered.

information.js:

```
<button class="active" onClick={() => useSetHero(hero)}>
```

hero.js:

```
export const useSetHero = (newHero) => {
    const UpdateHero = () => {
        const [hero, setHero] = useState(newHero);
        setHero(newHero);
    };

    return { UpdateHero };

}
```

the error message i am currently getting is:
React Hook "useHero" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Comment: Move the use state outside of update hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the state for the hook itself, not for a function within the hook.  For example:

```
export const useHero = (initialHero) => {
  const [hero, setHero] = useState(initialHero);

  const UpdateHero = (newHero) => {
    setHero(newHero);
  };

  return { UpdateHero };
}
```

Additionally, note the difference between `initialHero` and `newHero` here.  The former is used when first calling the hook, to initialize the first state value:

```
const { UpdateHero } = useHero(someValueHere);
```

And the latter is used when calling `UpdateHero` to update it to a new value:

```
<button class="active" onClick={() => UpdateHero(hero)}>
```

Note in the above lines that you don't invoke a hook *directly in the markup*.  Hooks are invoked early in the component (and always the same hooks in the same order on every render).  Data and/or functions *returned* by the hook can then be used later.

---

A couple notes:

1. Nothing ever uses `hero` here.  I imagine the hook would want to return that value as well so it can be used.
2. `UpdateHero` is superfluous here, you can just return `setHero`.

I'm assuming both of these are because this is a very minimalized example of what you're trying to do and the actual hook does more than this.  But otherwise, the hook shown *as is* could be simplified to:

```
export const useHero = (initialHero) => {
  const [hero, UpdateHero] = useState(initialHero);

  return { hero, UpdateHero };
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i was still getting an issue in a different line: <input id="name" value={hero.name} onChange={e => useHero((hero) => ({...hero, name: e.target.value}))}  placeholder='name' /> The error is the same as in the original post, i also edited the code a bit to fit your answer

Comment: @Jod: You don't invoke a hook directly in the markup like that.  Hooks are invoked at the start of the component.  Functions returned by the hook can be invoked later in the component.

Comment: I have stopped getting the error message now, the input isnt updating but i think i should be able to fix that myself, thanks for your help it is a huge relief